# Anything wrong with nested Perl subs, that are only called locally?

Tags: perl, memory, scope, nested

If I have the following code

```
sub a {
    my $id = shift;
    # does something
    print &a_section($texta);
    print &a_section($textb);
    sub a_section {
        my $text = shift;
        # combines the $id and the $text to create and return some result.
    }
}
```

Assuming `a_section` is called only by `a`, will I run into a memory leak, variable dependability, or other problem?

I am exploring this as an alternative so I can avoid the necessity of passing `$id` to `a_section`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, it's not a private sub. It's fully visible from the outside. Two, you will have problems.

```
$ perl -wE'
   sub outer {
      my ($x) = @_;
      sub inner { say $x; }
      inner();
   }
   outer(123);
   outer(456);
'
Variable "$x" will not stay shared at -e line 4.
123
123     <--- XXX Not 456!!!!
```

You could do:

```
sub a {
    my $id = shift;

    local *a_section = sub {
        my $text = shift;
        # combines the $id and the $text to create and return some result.
    };

    print a_section($texta);
    print a_section($textb);
}
```

(You can call the inner sub recursively using `a_section(...)`.)

or:

```
sub a {
    my $id = shift;

    my $a_section = sub {
        my $text = shift;
        # combines the $id and the $text to create and return some result.
    };

    print $a_section->($texta);
    print $a_section->($textb);
}
```

(Use `__SUB__->(...)` if you want to call the inner sub recursively to avoid memory leak, available in Perl 5.16+.)

Comment: You can also do this as `my $a_section = sub{...}; print $a_section->($texta)`.

Comment: @mkb, Yes, you could make the sub calls less readable and more prone to accidental memory leaks, but why would you want to? Besides, I've already added it to my post so I could mention how to avoid the memory leak.

Comment: @ikegami, Thanks for mentioning. Could you please explain why/whether it would be better to use `my` over `local` when defining the inner sub?

Comment: @George Bailey, For non-recursive subs, there's no difference. For recursive subs, you can suffer from memory leaks with the lexical (`$a_section`), but it can be avoided by using `__SUB__->(...)`. The catch is that `__SUB__` makes its debut in Perl 5.16 which isn't out yet. The glob (`*a_section`) version does not suffer from that memory leak and your sub calls look like sub calls. The down side is that it doesn't work for mutually recursive functions that both define inner subs with the same name, but you're never going to see that in your life.

Comment: Please clarify *"mutually recursive functions that both define inner subs with the same name"*. Thanks

Comment: @George Bailey, Yes. `*a_section` is a glob. Mutually recursive: a calls b, b calls a. Edited so it's a bit more readable.